# D7, Sorting / Grouping (Views Relationships with Entity Reference fields)

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, views

- I am rendering Name Tags for thousands of content nodes in one content type called “Cadet.”
- Each of these "Cadet" nodes specifies a single "Attendee" for an upcoming event.

**The situation:**

- Some attendees also need name tags printed out for their “friends” who are attending "with them."
- That is no problem—these “friends” obviously need their own node with the same fields to get their own name tag, so I distinguish that they are a “Friend of an Attendee” with a simple checkbox.
- To link them to the Cadet nodes they are attending with, I used an Entity Reference field.

**The sorting order / grouping problem:**

- When rendering the view, I need these “friends of attendees” to appear “right after” the attendee they are going with.

**The final question:**

- Using relationships, how could I get the Views module to sort the friends of attendees "right after" the attendee they are going with? There seems to be a need for "grouping" in this relationship, but after three days of trial and error, I cannot figure it out.

*I am technically using the [Views PDF](http://drupal.org/project/views_pdf) module, but it has the basic Views functions, so if it's possible with Views, it will probably be possible with this module.*

[In this link](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/9213/x7u.png), I've provided my settings in a compiled high resolution image with explanations on what I have done so far. If anyone would be able to direct me on the right path, I would appreciate it very much!

Thanks!